# Enable MFA for both password and key-based authentication

Tags: sshd, alma-linux, 2-factor-authentication

I've implemented Multi-Factor Authentication (MFA) for both password and key-based SSH logins on an AlmaLinux 9 server. While sshd typically handles key authentication directly, I've configured sshd to use PAM (Pluggable Authentication Modules) for MFA.

My current setup uses `publickey,keyboard-interactive` in the `AuthenticationMethods` option of sshd. However, I'd like to skip the password prompt in PAM if public key authentication is successful.

Does anyone have recommendations on how to achieve this? Here are some additional details that might be helpful:

sshd configuration

```
Match Address 213.10.11.21/32 LocalPort 22
    AllowUsers test
    KbdInteractiveAuthentication yes
    PasswordAuthentication yes
    PubkeyAuthentication no
    AuthenticationMethods password,keyboard-interactive publickey,keyboard-interactive
```

PAM configuration

```
auth    required      pam_unix.so    no_warn try_first_pass
auth [success=1 default=ignore] pam_access.so accessfile=/etc/security/access-local.conf
auth    required      pam_google_authenticator.so
```